# How do I use PHP to supply info to JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a simple image-looping script that changes the `src` of an image.

```
function cycleNext()
{
    ++imgIndex;

    if(imgIndex>imgCount)
    {
        imgIndex = 1;
    }

    setImgSrc(imgIndex);
}
```

However, at present, I'm (shudder) *manually entering* `imgCount` in my script. The alternative is server-side, but I don't know how to fetch this information. I imagine it's pretty simple, though.

How can I use PHP to supply this script with the number of images in the folder?

Comment: Exactly the same way you supply info to HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$directory = "Your directory";
$filecount = count(glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg"));
$filecount += count(glob("" . $directory . "*.png"));
?>
```

Repeat the 2nd line for each extension you wish to count.

```
function cycleNext()
{
    ++imgIndex;

    if (imgIndex > <?php echo $filecount;?>)
    {
        imgIndex = 1;
    }

    setImgSrc(imgIndex);
}
```

That should do it.

EDIT:

```
function cycleNext(imgCount)
{
    ++imgIndex;

    if (imgIndex > imgCount)
    {
        imgIndex = 1;
    }

    setImgSrc(imgIndex);
}
```

Then when you call cycleNext, call it with the variable.

```
cycleNext(<?php echo $filecount; ?>);
```

Comment: That will work if the script is part of the page. If it's a separate .js file, then I think there would be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, I just assumed the JS was inline.  If the js is not inline, make the imgcount a function variable and pass it through with PHP.

Comment: Thanks, if a typical source is "graphics/x.jpg" then $directory would be "graphics/", right?

Comment: @ Gazler, you mean define imgCount inline and then I can call it with my external .js file?

Comment: And, it wouldn't be a problem if the script were in the same directory, right?

Comment: I have edited it to show what I meant.  And the directory would be 'graphics/' yes.

Answer (score 1):

if the .js file is a separate file. then you can do this:

change the `.js` for a `.php`

then you can add `<?php  ?>` tags just like you do in your `.php` files.

just don't forget to add the header in the code, indicating that the file is a javascript file. like that:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/javascript"); ?>
```

and you will call the file with it's actual name `src="file.php"`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in three ways:

1. Making your .js file a .php file (with the correct mime-type) and just use an echo in that .js.php-file
2. include the javascript to the <head> tag of your page
3. echo a variable into a <script> tag in your <head> and use it in your javascript file. Example:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     var imgCount = <?php echo $imagecount ?>
   </script>;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

During the generation of the HTML code, simply insert a `<script>` line, for instance

```
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
  echo 'var imgCount=' . $NumberOfImages . ';';
  echo '</script>';
```

Just ensure that line is provided before `cycleNext()` is called (or imgCount is used).